LAPACK installed but "not enabled"
I am currently trying to do some tensor cross interpolation using something called xfac. This work is being done on an ubuntu VM (VM because I wasn't ready to fully transition to linux but it was heavily reccomended), in python. I have been using pipenv to manage my venv. I am having to use numpy 1.26.4 because of imcompatibility with xfac. Xfac cannot be installed with pip, if desired I can specify more about xfac.
Anyway time for the problem. When I run the example code given by the devs of xfac, I get a specific error message :
"RuntimeError: qr_econ(): use of LAPACK must be enabled" 

It prompts this in refrence to a method from xfac.
To be clear, I have installed LAPACK. Yet for some reason it stays not enabled. Any suggestions on where this could come from are appreciated. My most recent theory comes from a lecturer, he suggested that when I build xfac with CMAKE I had to add something in to enable LAPACK, however CMAKE is completely new to me still, so I've been hesistant to try and figure that out.

Here is the full error. I have tried just reinstalling LAPACK and BLAS, getting the dev packages, checking all my dependencies. All sorts with no success.
Edit : I was not aware this would end up automatically going public I will edit the content soon to be more usefull, however I have been under the weather and have work due so please be patient. I have also come accross an issue with my package manager that I must resolve seperately before continuing with this either way.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do share the code that you are using to call xfac from python. Also please tell us how exactly did you install LAPACK and BLAS on your ubuntu VM.
